# Simplifying this form validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html, validation

Can anyone please help me to simplify this form validation script?  It works great but I was just wondering if I can get some help to make it simpler.  Your opinion on the approach I used below is also welcome (i.e it is good or bad practice/method).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var FormValidation = function(form){


             this.messages = {

                required    : 'This field should not be empty',
                email       : 'Please enter  valid email',
                number      : 'Please enter  valid number',
                min         : 'This field length should be minimum ',
                max         : 'This field length should not exceed ',
                range       : 'This field length between  '
            };

            validator = this;

            var currentmsg =this;

            this.required = function(value){
                var valid = (value.length > 0);
                return {status: valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.required};
            }

            this.email = function(value){
                var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/ ;
                var valid = pattern.test(value);
                return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.email};
            }

            this.number = function(value){
                var pattern = /^[0-9]+/ ;
                var valid = pattern.test(value);
                return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.number};
            }

            this.min = function(value,args){
                if(value.length > 0){
                    var valid = (value.length >= args[0])
                    return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.min + args[0] };
                }
            }

            this.max = function(value,args){
                    if(value.length > 0){
                        var valid = (value.length <= args[0])
                        return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.max + args[0] };
                    }
                }

            this.range = function(value,args){
                var valid = (value.length >= args[0] && value.length <= args[1])
                return { 
                    status:valid, 
                    message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.range + args[0] + ' and ' + args[1]
                    };
            }

            this.validators = {
                required : validator.required,
                email    : validator.email,
                number   : validator.number,
                range    : validator.range,
                max      : validator.max,
                min      : validator.min 
            };

            this.validate = function(form){
                var elements = form.elements;
                var status = true;
                for(var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++){
                    var validate = elements[i].getAttribute('validate');
                    if(!validate){      
                        continue;
                    }
                    var types = validate.split(' ');
                    for(var j = 0; j < types.length; j++){
                        var result = this.validateField(elements[i], types[j]);
                        if(!result) { 
                            continue 
                        }
                        this.displayErrors(elements[i], result);
                        if(!result.status) {                            
                            status = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return status;
            }

            this.displayErrors = function(element, result){
                element.className = result.status ? '' : 'error';
                var elErr =element.errorMsg;
                if(elErr!=null)
                    elErr.className = result.status ? '' :'valerr'
                    if(!element.errorMsg){
                        elErr = document.createElement("div");
                        elErr.id = 'valerr';
                        element.parentNode.appendChild(elErr);
                        element.errorMsg = elErr;
                    }
                elErr.innerHTML = result.message;
            }

            this.validateField = function (element, type){
                var validationType = type;
                var args ;
                if(type.indexOf("(")!= -1 && type.indexOf(")") != -1){
                    var result = this.getArguments(type);
                    validationType = result.type;
                    args = result.argsList;
                }
                validator = this.validators[validationType];
                if(validator != null){
                    return validator(element.value ,args);
                }
                return null;
            }

            this.getArguments = function(type){
                var validationtype = type.substring(0,type.indexOf("("));
                var args = type.substring(type.indexOf("(")+1,type.indexOf(")")).split(',');
                return { type : validationtype, argsList : args}
            }

            this.init = function() {
                var curForm = this;
                var forms = document.forms;
                for(var i = 0; i < forms.length ; i++){
                    if(forms[i].getAttribute('validate')!=null){
                        forms[i].onsubmit = function(){
                            return curForm.validate(this);
                        };
                    }
                }       
            }
    }

    window.onload = function() {        
        var formValidation = new FormValidation();
        formValidation.init();
    }
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="#" validate>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" validate="required min(5)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile No :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" validate="required number min(10) max(10)">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="" validate="required email"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit"  value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: If that is meant to be jQuery plugin you are not wrapping it correctly into the jQuery namepsace. Could cause issues but its jsut precautin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spent a little hacking away at this to simplify the code. I wrote comments on changes inline the script, let me know if you have any questions

Some thoughts on the changes. Notice that how I restructured your validators in the form

```
validatorName: {
   message: 'fail msg',
   classes: 'add classes to element on fail',
   test: function(){return true;}
};
```

I've made some validators of my own and this is my personal preference for structuring validators and it allows us to due away with that weird `currentMessage` variable.

I've also fixed a bunch of your linting errors - there were a lot of them so I didn't really comment on them. In the future run your code through [jshint](http://jshint.com/) before posting it :)

One last thought. There doesn't seem much of a reason for you to be writing this code as a class as its most likely a singleton and you're not writing the code on the prototype. I've resturctured your code to be a more conventional singleton rather than a class

Here's the start of a counter proposal... Theres likely bugs but the code is a great deal simpler and uses less hackery than your original approach.

```
var FormValidation = function (form) {

    //Remove Gloabl variable and duplicate as mentioned by @konijn
    //replaces validator and currentMessage
    var self = {};

    //Counter proposal: I suggest you have an object of validators instead of
    // Dividing the parts of validators between messages/validators/this. Centeralize
    // all parts in a single object
    //Structure of a validator {test: fn(value, args) -> bool, message:str, classes:str}
    // Advantages: more explicit and you dont need that ugly current message variable
    self.validators = {
        required: {
            message: 'This field should not be empty',
            classes: 'reqerr',
            test   : function (value) {
                return value.length > 0;
            }
        },
        email: {
            message: 'Please enter  valid email',
            test   : function (value) {
                //no need for a pattern var, this is explicit as it gets
                return /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(value); //comment what is a valid email or a link where you got the regexp
            }
        },
        number: {
            message: 'Please enter  valid number',
            classes: 'valerr',
            test   : function (value) {
                return /^\d+$/.test(value); //simpler number regexp and ensures entire string is numbers not just start characters
            }
        },
        min: {
            message: 'This field length should be minimum ',
            test: function (value, args) {
                return value.length > 0 && value.length >= args[0];
            }
        },
        max: {
            message: 'This field length should not exceed ',
            test   : function (value, args) {
                return value.length > 0 && value.length <= args[0];
            }
        },
        range: {
            message: 'This field length between ',
            test   : function (value, args) {
                return value.length >= args[0] && value.length <= args[1];
            }
        }
    };

    var getArguments = function (type) {
        var validationtype = type.substring(0, type.indexOf("("));
        var args = type.substring(type.indexOf("(") + 1, type.indexOf(")")).split(',');
        return {
            type    : validationtype,
            argsList: args
        };
    };

    var displayErrors = function (element, validator) {
        element.className = validator.classes || 'error';
        var elErr = element.errorMsg;
        if (!element.errorMsg) {
            elErr = document.createElement("div"); //dont set the id if you're not gonna use it
            element.parentNode.appendChild(elErr);
            element.errorMsg = elErr; //Warning this can make old ie very slow to unload
        }
        elErr.innerHTML = validator.message;
    };

    //This is your old validateField function modified to show the error if it fails in order to simplify the validate function
    var validateField = function (element, type) {
        //no need to make a var equal to a param
        var valid = true;
        var args, validator;
        //better to use a regexp here to get args
        if (/\(.*\)/.test(type)) {
            var result  = getArguments(type);
            type        = result.type;
            args        = result.argsList;
        }
        validator = self.validators[type];
        if (validator) { //no need for the != null
            valid = validator.test(element.value, args);
            if (!valid) {
                //display errors
                displayErrors(element, validator);
            }
        }
        return valid;
    };

    self.validate = function (form) {
        var elements = form.elements;
        var status = true;
        var element, validate, types, result, //create variables outside the loop
            i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            element = elements[i];
            validate = element.getAttribute('validate');
            if (!validate) {
                continue;
            }
            types = validate.split(' ');
            for (j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (types[i] && //not empty string and
                !validateField(element, types[j]) //if not valid
                ) {
                    status = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    };

    self.init     = function () {
        var forms = document.forms;
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            if (forms[i].getAttribute('validate') != null) {
                forms[i].onsubmit = function () {
                    return self.validate(this); //this refers to the current form
                };
            }
        }
    };

    return self;
};
```

Here's a demo of your code up and running: http://jsbin.com/ropi/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

This is already quite tight, I like it.

There is one big thing that jumps out:

```
validator = this;
var currentmsg =this;
```

You are using `this`, and `validator` and `currentmsg` all really pointing to `this`, that is making it harder than needed. Furthermore you escape scope by not using `var` for `validator`!

Comment: Shall I delete `validator = this;
var currentmsg =this;` then mate?

Comment: I think you should, and simply point to `this` in all cases.

Comment: Please can you help me do it? I tried but can't figure out how to exactly do it. I am not really expert in JavaScript and had to get lot of help to get the above working