# Simplifying this form validation script - version 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form

A week ago, I have asked how to [simplify a form validation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40964/simplifying-this-form-validation-script/41001?noredirect=1#41001).  From the answers, the code now is improved.  Can anyone please share their opinion on the approach used below and advise me if there is a better way to cut it?

```
//Create object to hold the different error messages
var errorMessage = new Object();
errorMessage.required   = "This field can not be empty";
errorMessage.email      = "Please enter a valid email address";
errorMessage.number     = "Please only enter numbers in this field";
errorMessage.min        = "This field should be minimum ";
errorMessage.max        = "This field should be maximum ";
errorMessage.date       = "Please use the date format outlined above";

$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();
   if (mtdValidate()) {
     $submit = $(this).find('button[id="submit"]');
       $inputs = $(this).find('input, textarea, select, label');
       var posting = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $('#contactForm').serialize());

       posting.done(function(data) {
          $('span.error').remove();

          if (data == "1") {
             $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
             $submit.add($inputs).addClass('sent').prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
             $submit.after('<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 15px 5px; color: #bd3d3d">Failed to send the message, please try again later.</span>');
             $submit.text('Try Again');
          }
       });
   }
});

$("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").blur(function() {
   console.log("we blur now");

   if ( $(this).hasClass("required") ) {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.required);
         isFormValid = false;
      }

   } else if ($(this).hasClass("email")) {
      var emailRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      var emailIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (emailRegEx.test(emailIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.email);
         isFormValid = false;
      }

   } else if ($(this).hasClass("number")) {
      var numRegEx = /^[0-9]+/;
      var numIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (numRegEx.test(numIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.number);
         isFormValid = false;
      }

   } else if ($(this).hasClass("date")) {
      var dateRegEx = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
      var dateIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (dateRegEx.test(dateIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.date);
         isFormValid = false;
      }
   }
});

function mtdValidate() {

   //Form is treated as being valid until validation fails
   var isFormValid = true;

   //Reset Error Messages on each submit press
   resetErrorMessages();

   //Loop through fields marked as required
   $("#contactForm input.required").each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.required);
         isFormValid = false;
      }
   });

   //Loop through fields marked as email
   $("#contactForm input.email").each(function() {
      var emailRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      var emailIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (emailRegEx.test(emailIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.email);
         isFormValid = false;
      }
   });

   //Loop through fields marked as number
   $("#contactForm input.number").each(function() {
      var numRegEx = /^[0-9]+/;
      var numIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (numRegEx.test(numIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.number);
         isFormValid = false;
      }
   });

   //Loop through fields marked as date
   $("#contactForm input.date").each(function() {
      var dateRegEx = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
      var dateIn = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (dateRegEx.test(dateIn) == false) {
         manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.date);
         isFormValid = false;
      }
   });

   //Loop through fields marked with min and max classes
   $("#contactForm input").each(function() {
      if ( $(this).attr("class") ) {

         if( $(this).attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/) ) {
            var minClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/).toString();
            minVal = parseInt(minClass.match(/[0-9]+/));

            if ( $.trim($(this).val().length) < minVal )  {
               manageErrorMinMax($(this), errorMessage.min, minVal);
               isFormValid = false;
            }

         }

         if ( $(this).attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/) ) {
            var maxClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/).toString();
            maxVal = parseInt(maxClass.match(/[0-9]+/));

            if ( $.trim($(this).val().length) > maxVal )  {
               manageErrorMinMax($(this), errorMessage.max, maxVal);
               isFormValid = false;
            }

         }
      }
   });

   return isFormValid;

}

function resetErrorMessages() {
   $("span.error").remove();
   $("input .error").removeClass("error");
}

function manageErrorMessage(that, errorMessageIn) {
   $(that).addClass('error');
   if ( !$(that).next().is("span") ) {
      $(that).after('<span class="error"></span>');
   }
   $(that).next().html(errorMessageIn);
}

function manageErrorMinMax(that, errorMessageIn, value) {
   $(that).addClass('error');
   if ( !$(that).next().is("span") ) {
      $(that).after('<span class="error"></span>');
   }
   $(that).next().html(errorMessageIn + value + " charaters long.");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- I'd almost always rather use object literals `{}` than `new Object()` for this. Much less verbose and easier to read.

  ```
  var errorMessage = {
    required   : "This field can not be empty",
    email      : "Please enter a valid email address",
    number     : "Please only enter numbers in this field",
    min        : "This field should be minimum ",
    max        : "This field should be maximum ",
    date       : "Please use the date format outlined above"
  };
  ```
- You use `$('#contactForm')` a lot. Save it, and use it as context to your other selectors:

  ```
  var $form = $('#contactForm');   // for example this will return all     
  var $inputs = $('input', $form); // inputs that are decendants of $form
  ```

  Also notice how I prefix variables with `$` to denote that they contain jQuery objects. Makes it easier to tell the difference between vars.
- If you have form elements that need to be validated via regexes, have you thought about putting them in the DOM as `data` attributes? This keeps formatting rules in one place.

  ```
  <input type="text" class="number" data-validation="/^[0-9]+/" />
  ```

  It also means you don't have to do those multiple iterations. Also, if you use `$(this)` more than once, save it as a var.

  ```
  $('input', $form).each(function () {
     var $el = $(this); 
     var regex = new RegEx($el.data('validation'));
     [...]
  });
  ```
- You could use a callback in your `$.post` to save creating the variable;

  ```
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $('#contactForm').serialize(), 
       function (data) {
         $('span.error').remove();
         [...]
       });
  ```
- This is daft:

  > ```
  >    if (dateRegEx.test(dateIn) == false) {
  >        manageErrorMessage( $(this), errorMessage.date);
  >       isFormValid = false;
  >     }
  > ```

  No need to check against `false`, it is false.

  ```
    if (dateRegEx.test(dateIn)) {
       [...]
    }
  ```
- One more.... Thanks to `Hydrothermal` for making me realise.
  This statement will return true if `data` is any state of truthy because the values are coerced.

  > ```
  >     if (data == "1") {
  > ```

  For example:

  ```
    true == "1" // true
    1 == "1"    // true
  ```

  It might be that this doesn't matter in this case, but you should always use `===` to compare values by identity rather than equality.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a best practices thing than an actual issue, but you should usually use `===` instead of `==` when doing comparisons. `===` is a "strict" comparison, and is a little more predictable in its behavior. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2789699) is an excellent explanation of why, if you're curious.

Comment: Also there are some dodgey comparisons going on like this: `data == "1"`. Should data be a String or an number? Does it matter? This statement tells me nothing.

Comment: Haha, also `(data == "1")` is true if `data` is truthy.